# Will low well water pH cause plumbing damage or health problems?

Tags: plumbing, water, well, water-filtration

Our well has been having some bacteria issues so we are installing a UV filter system. The installer also recommended a system to correct the acidic quality of our water which is PH 6.0. He said it can corrode pipes and its not healthy to consume copper. My questions are

-The house is from 1974 and mostly used for weekends. Am I really in danger of pipes leaking in the next 10-20 years from this level?

-Is there any health risk to this level?

Really just trying to figure out if I being upsold or this is a valid concern. Most of the info on the web is from companies that sell water filtration products so I don’t know how objective they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pH of 6.0 is not unreasonably low for a well-water system.  That's at the low end of the "normal" range but not anything I'd worry about.

Copper pipes will not be "dissolved" at this pH level and the minute amount of Cu that you are consuming is not a concern.  It's a common mineral and it is not generally harmful to humans, certainly not in the quantities you're talking about here.

I'm sure the installer you talked to has a solution to this "problem" and he's trying to sell you one.

Comment: I would agree but acid bases are hard on galvanized and cast pipe drains

Answer (score 1):

No, but you may want to filter it inside the house for drinking if you don't like the taste of well water. Typically Iron is more of a problem to drink (and messing your laundry up).

I'd direct you here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/254155501_Alkalinity_pH_and_copper_corrosion_by-product_release

Carbonates are nastier than 'milk' which is what pH 6.0 is approximately.

Not all acid is bad.

Comment: "Not all acid is bad"  <--  that's what Timothy Leary said

Comment: I thought folks would like that.

Answer (score 0):

A pH of 6 for a natural water is surprisingly acidic in my experience. My first thought is not to believe it. You can check it inexpensively with a pH test kit from a tropical fish shop. Our city water is from a river ,so expect acidic surface water .I never measured anything below pH 6.6 . Many well water sources are limestone aquifers, they would never produce pH 6. However , would be very low , less than 0.001 " per year, at full time use with pH 6.

Comment: It is difficult to find corrosion data for these conditions as corrosion is not expected.

Comment: yes, I ran into that too. Nothing I saw or scanned had much of anything at 6.0. I wonder if that was a litmus test paper that was used... and can only read '6' which has an improper significant figure assigned to it (the .0)

Comment: I had it professionally tested and they found 5.8

Comment: Did the test show what (anion) was causing it ,such as chloride ?